# slideIn after slideOut in mootools 1.1

Tags: mootools, delay, mootools-events

I am trying to build a custom code in **mootools 1.1**, what am doing is when you click a button the container slideOut first and delay for few seconds let say 2sec then slideIn again, firstly the container is open...

The code:-

```
$('showMore').addEvent('click', function(e){
   e = new Event(e);
   mySlide.slideOut().delay(5000).slideIn();
   e.stop();
});
```

The code is not working, it slides out but not the next one...

Comment: why on earth are you using mootools 1.1 and not the new builds ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation on the delay function - you invoke it on the function, not the object.

```
mySlide.slideOut().slideIn.delay(5000, mySlide);
```